# Do we welcome questions written (partially) in languages other than English?

Tags: discussion

There's only been one such question so far, but, depending on weather this question is accepted as a good one or not, it could set up future standards for the site, so I feel it is important:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/en-shs-comment-participer-a-la-grande-conversation-scientifique-sans-renoncer-a

There is a small part of the question in English, which actually sounds partially interesting to me. But then, there's a *big chunk of French!*

I sometimes come to this site to read up on life in Academia and inform myself about how things work where I'm not. I do participate a little, but much, much more, I *read the questions and answers that seem interesting*.

Seeing this question, I couldn't help but feel just a little bit disappointed. There's this question, that might be nice, but I'm missing half of it. Seeing what Google Translate does to it just makes it more disappointing.

And then, there's this two interesting *answers*, on which *I do not want to vote*, because *I do not know if they are relevant*.

As it could determine a future standard (accept or not questions in other languages), I think it is important that there's an discussion within the community.

Comment: I fully agree with your assessment and concern.

Comment: @posdef yup, but it looks like I should have dug deeper (actually, I didn't dig at all) before asking the question as there is an answer for a few years already. Still, I feel kind of sorry for the (possibly) good answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question has been [answered by Jeff Atwood on the Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) a few years ago, and the short answer is that English is the language of the Stack Exchange community.

Comment: tres bien.. (sorry, could not resist)

Comment: ...with the [exception of questions being specifically intended to be in that other language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53004/146482), e.g. the [many language learner sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) like http://french.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, apart from these, most attempts à la "StackOverflow in French" have so far failed to launch from [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) - and at least IMHO it's a good thing that the potentially good answers of polyglots don't get scattered too much

Comment: ... so if you come across a non-English question in a language you speak, and the question is a good one, then edit and translate it.

Answer (score -3):

This is a site for academics, and academics should be able to read a little bit of French.

Comment: (That's not to say that this particular question was wrongly closed.  It's not a SE-style focused question, and there's more than a little bit of French.  But I don't think we should just assume that language policies appropriate for programmers are appropriate for academics.)

Comment: I know a lot of excellent academics from my field in Czech Republic. Would you then advise me to learn enough Czech to communicate about science, especially since there exists a possibility that I might go for an exchange there at some point?

Comment: I don't think academics should be expected to have a *conversational* knowledge of French, just to be comfortable reading a little bit of it.  This is why Ph.D. programs have (written) language exams, because there's a *lot* of academic literature in French.  (Not so much in Czech.)

Comment: I did my PhD programme in France, and I never had any sort of a language exam, written or otherwise, as a part of my PhD programme. And I would assume there is a lot of academic literature written in any language with a large number of speakers and a strong "research record"; maybe not so much in Czech since it is a small country in comparison, but I'm sure there's a lot of academic literature in German as well for example.